# Visual Studio 2010 "INS" & "OVR"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What is the meaning of the "INS" and "OVR" messages at the right bottom of the vs 2010 screen?

[image: vs 2010 ins & ovr messages]

Comment: thx for answers. I found the exact link about the topic. Their names are "INSERT" and "OVERSTRIKE".. link here --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.setinsmode.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

INSERT or OVERTYPE or something like that.

It does the same as if you press the INSERT touch on your keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

It tells you whether you are in "Insert" or "Overtype" mode.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key):

> It is primarily used to switch between the two text-entering modes on
>   a personal computer (PC) or word processor. **The first is overtype
>   mode, in which the cursor, when typing, overwrites any text that is
>   present on and after its current location. The other is insert mode,
>   where the cursor inserts a character at its current position, forcing
>   all characters past it one position further.** The insert/overtype mode
>   toggling is not global for the computer or even for a single
>   application but rather local to the text input window in which the
>   Insert key was pressed.
>
> On early text-based computing environments and terminals, when the
>   cursor was in overtype mode, it was represented as a block that
>   surrounded the entire letter to be overstruck; when in insert mode,
>   the cursor consisted of the vertical bar that is highly common among
>   modern applications, or a blinking underline under the position where
>   a new character would be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

```
INS - Insertion
OVR - Overwriting
```

When the mode is INS it will insert text at insertion point else will overwrite.